# Android Square Register API: ILLEGAL_LOCATION_ID

Tags: android, square-connect

I am integrating Square into my Android app.

I am struggling with where to find the `locationId` to pass to the `enforceBusinessLocation()` method. I've set up a location in my [Square dashboard](https://squareup.com/dashboard/locations/) but it isn't obvious where to get the `locationId` from.

I've tried using the location **nickname** (I tried both mixed case and uppercase - so, in my case, "mwe" and "MWE"), but that didn't work. It results in:

> ILLEGAL_LOCATION_ID: The LOCATION_ID parameter does not match the ID
>   of the business location currently logged in to Square Register.

I have selected that same location when logging into the Square Register app on the device.

I understand the `locationId` is optional, but I would like to include it.

So where to find the `locationId` as required for `enforceBusinessLocation()`?

Comment: I actually found the IDs when clicking a link on the contact form ( https://squareup.com/help/gb/en/contact?prefill=developer_api ) to report this issue. By inspecting the location fields with Firebug, I was able to find the 13-character `locationId`s. But what is the normal way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much easier way to get it. Just [log in](https://squareup.com/dashboard/) and click on **Accounts & Settings**, click on **Locations** (here's a [shortcut](https://squareup.com/dashboard/locations)), click the location and then you can see URL of the page change. The location ID is the last part of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can get your locations with the `/v1/me/locations` or `/v2/locations` endpoints.

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-listlocations
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#get-locations