# Square Connect API - how to get location_id?

Tags: square-connect

- I have integrate the iOS SDK and its working fine with Payment process. After payment successfully done I am getting transaction_id and other 2 ids.
- So now, I want to list all the transactions https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-listtransactions
  I have Application ID and Personal Access Token of my app.
- I referred Square Connect API. But it requires location_id to be passed with the HTTP request https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpointpaths
- I don’t know from where I get the location_id of my app. Once I get location_id I can make request and get all transactions and then I can make refund request as well.

Any suggestions/Help ?

Comment: There is a quicker / more convenient way than the accepted answer. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39733629/1617737).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get your `location_id` you should call the [locations](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#navsection-location) endpoint and pick which location you'd like to make the requests on the behalf of.

Comment: I am able to get `location_id`. Is it changeable ? I mean should I hardcode this value in app or should I call API after some period of time ?

Comment: If your business only has one location, then you should be fine to hardcode it.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to your [locations list](https://squareup.com/dashboard/locations) and then clicking a location. The location id would be shown in your URL after that.